# eliminar links discord canal ID

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear un bot en python para poder eliminar los enlaces, pero mi problema es el siguiente No sé cómo agregar más canales con el ID al código

Aquí les dejo mi código

```
import discord
import re
 
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   
   urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',message.content.lower())
   if urls and message.channel.id == 5415479575324880906:
       
       await message.channel.send("link borrado")
       await message.delete()
  
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("yeah!")
      
client.run("")
```

Comment: los snippets solo se usan con código html, css y JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla es en esta parte:

```
if urls and message.channel.id == 5415479575324880906: 
    await message.channel.send("link borrado")
    await message.delete()
```

Hacerlo de esta forma:

```
if urls and message.channel.id in [5415479575324880906, OTRAS, IDS]:
    await message.channel.send("link borrado")
    await message.delete()
```

En la primera solo te permite establecer la igualdad entre el `channel.id` y una única variable. Utilizando el operador `in` podrás establecer si el `channel.id` se encuentra dentro de la `lista` o `iterable` que se encuentra al otro lado de la operacion!

Saludos!

Comment: En lo posible agregar una descripción de lo que hace el código y mencionar en qué se equivocó quien pregunta. Es importante aprender de los errores y no solo copiar y pegar la solución (en caso de quién pregunta). Aunque esto es más una opinión personal no se si va con la filosofía de stackoverflow.